What's the right way of setting up a proxy in a React/Vite application for production?
I noticed that the proxy configuration in Vite only works for the development server. I want to make that work in production environment as well.
What would be the alternative to achieving that same behaviour? Basically I just want to call an API using the proxy because I don't want to expose sensitive information of the request in the client side.
Could I use http-proxy-middleware in the vite.config.js file? If so, what would be the right way of doing it?
